Verb tense use in specific context or possibility of alternatives
In the following sentence,I wonder which verb usage works best.
The sentence is ''I explained to them the reasons for wanting to go there/why I wanted to go there''
Which one is correct ?
''Les expliqué las razones por las que quiero ir allí/querría ir/quisiera ir/quería ir''
My conversation is in the past where I explain my reasons. However, I don't think the imperfect works best as ,I still want to go there.
I feel it should be ''quiero'',present tense,because I still want to go and the present tense works in the near future also.
Equally, I feel,the conditional''querría''sounds ok and the imperfect subjunctive ''quisiera'' as it is hypothetical and not 100 per cent certain but rather hopeful of going. (It is a prize of a holiday).
Anyway,I would love clarification.I feel,it is like in English where you can say it in different ways. That is,''''why I would like to go'' or ''I explained why I wanted to go'' or''why I want to go''.
The confusion,for me, is mainly with, in English, the idea of ''why I wanted to go''.
Am I correct in thinking that, although ,it is correct in English to say this, in this context , however, in Spanish, it is incorrect because although my conversation is in the past ,my desire to go is continuous.
Please clarify and correct me in any wrong assumptions here. Although,I regularly check grammar books ,I can't find this sort of specific  explanation in them .

Any of the four options is possible. It all depends on what you want to say in English. If it is "wanted," then you should use "quería."

But I find that there are some parts missing between the English version and the Spanish one.

I explained to them the reasons for wanting to go there

It can be translated as

Les expliqué las razones para ir allí

"For + gerund" usually is translated as "para + infinitivo"

A different thing is having

I explained to them the reasons that I had for going there

That I would translate as

Les expliqué las razones que tenía para ir allí

I'm not fully sure how to express in English that you still have (in the present) the same reasons for going there. Maybe

I explained to them the reasons why I would like to be there.

If you still have the same reasons and you want to remark that, in Spanish it would be

Les expliqué las razones por las que todavía quiero ir allí

or

Les expliqué las razones por las que querría ir allí


¡Hola!
Lo cierto es que las diferencias entre las distintas opciones son sutiles. Intento aclarar a continuación la utilización que daría a cada una de ellas

"Les expliqué las razones por las que quiero | querría | quisiera
ir allí"

Se lo expliqué el otro día (pasado) pero a día de hoy (cuando estoy diciendo la frase) todavía no he ido. A nivel personal "quisiera" es la que menos utilizaría de los tres, aunque tampoco sería incorrecta.

"Les expliqué las razones por las que quería ir allí"

El deseo de querer ir forma parte del pasado (en aquel momento quería ir)

Resumen: la explicación fue hecha en pasado, por lo que está bien arrancar con pretérito aunque también sería igualmente válido arrancar con presente histórico (narrar el pasado en presente). Pero supongamos que decidimos explicarlo en pretérito. Tenemos:

Les expliqué las razones por las que (yo) ..... ir allí.


quiero: tu deseo para ir allí sigue vigente.
quisiera: ídem a quiero, aunque expresado de una forma más indirecta. Generalmente se usa para arrancar frases en casos como ‘Hoy quisiera ir a la playa’, cosas por el estilo.
quería: tu deseo expiró
querría: en ningún momento pensaste en ir, estás suponiendo posibles causas que te motivarían. Este uso es más común en preguntas como ‘Quién querría hacer eso?’, es decir llevado a nuestro caso ‘Por qué querría ir allí?’, aunque es igualmente válido en tu ejemplo con el mismo sentido.


Sí, creo que ''..por las que quiero'' o ''les expliqué las razones para ir allí'' suenan mejor.gracias
